# How to assume two union types as the same

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm making a function with two same union type as arguments.
How can they be assumed as the same type in switch statement?

I'm trying this using Typescript@3.5.1

```js
interface Square {
  kind: 'square'
  size: number
}
interface Rectangle {
  kind: 'rectangle'
  width: number
  height: number
}

type Shape = Square | Rectangle

function areas(s: Shape, ss: Shape) {
  if (s.kind !== ss.kind) return  // check if the kind of them are the same
  switch (s.kind) {
    case 'square':
      return s.size * s.size + ss.size * ss.size // error
    case 'rectangle':
      return s.height * s.width + ss.height * ss.width // error
  }
}
```

This stetement makes an error such as

> Property 'size' does not exist on type 'Shape'.
>
> Property 'size' does not exist on type 'Rectangle'.ts(2339)

but I expect no error occurs because equivalence of `s.kind`
and `ss.kind` is already checked.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because both `s` and `ss` are just a `Shape` the entire time.  The compiler knows that both have a value called "kind" but still does not know the actual type of each.  A `Square` might have a "size" but a `Shape` does not and the compiler knows it.

Creating a function that needs to know the details of a `Shape` defeats the purpose of using an `interface` in the first place.  You could achieve what you want much more cleanly like so:

```
interface Square {
  area(): number
  size: number
}

interface Rectangle {
  area(): number
  width: number
  height: number
}

type Shape = Square | Rectangle

function areas(s: Shape, ss: Shape) {
   return s.area() + ss.area()
}
```

However if you really want to do it you could do it by explicitly casting each object to the desired type before you access it's properties

```
interface Square {
  size: number
}

interface Rectangle {
  width: number
  height: number
}

type Shape = Square | Rectangle

function areas(s: Shape, ss: Shape) {
    if (typeof s != typeof ss) {
        return
    }
    switch (typeof s) {
        case 'Square': {
            s = s as Square; ss = ss as Square
            return s.size * s.size + ss.size * ss.size
        }
        case 'Rectangle': {
            s = s as Rectangle; ss = ss as Rectangle
            return s.width * ss.height + s.width * ss.height
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this second example won't actually work (even if you explicitly declare something as one of your union types), despite the fact that is compiles since `typeof` will return `"object"`, but it demonstrates how to tell the compiler which type to use (using [as](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions))

```
class SquareImpl implements Square {
    size: number = -1

    constructor(size : number) {
        this.size = size
    }
}

let s : Square = new SquareImpl(10)
console.log(typeof s) // logs "object"
```

You might try and implement it using `instanceof`:

```
if (s instanceof Square && ss instanceof Square) {
    s = s as Square; ss = ss as Square
    return s.size * s.size + ss.size * ss.size
}
// similar code for Rectangle etc
```

However Typescript won't let you use check if an object implements an interface at runtime, so you're back to using a custom type guard:

```
interface Square {
    kind: string
    sameShape(obj: Shape): boolean 
    area(): number
    size: number
} 

class SquareImpl implements Square {
    kind: string = "square"
    size: number = -1
    area() { return this.size * this.size }
    sameShape(obj: Shape): obj is Square {
        return obj.kind == "square"
    }
    constructor(size: number) { this.size = size }
}
// similar for Rectangle

...
let r : Rectangle = new RectangleImpl(1, 2)
let s : Square = new SquareImpl(3)
let ss : Square = new SquareImpl(2)
if (s.sameShape(ss)) {
    console.log('s + ss: '+ s.area() + ss.area())
}
if (s.sameShape(r)) {
    console.log('s + r: '+ s.area() + r.area())
}
```

Comment: Is there an advantage to use this over [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) in this particular question?

Comment: @ErikPhilips `instanceof` is a arguably a better choice, but this is still not the best way to do this - just trying to replicate the OP's code while still showing that having a property to hold the type name is not necessary

Comment: Wait, why `s.constructor.name` (which might just be `"Object"`, since nothing says there is a `class Square` or `class Rectangle`) instead of `s.kind`?  This is a nearly canonical example of a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions); the compiler certainly does understand, when you check `s.kind === 'square'`, that `s` is a `Square` and not a `Rectangle`.  The issue in OP's question has to do with two correlated types, which this answer only addresses by type asserting `s` and `ss` to the same types.

Comment: @jcalz I agree.  If you feel like modifying my answer to address those concerns go ahead.  I wanted to demonstrate a solution to the core concern of "how do I let the compiler know what type this Object is once I know it" rather than "what type is this Object".  Either way, I don't believe that the second version is at all the way the general use case presented by the OP should be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Convincing the compiler that two variables of union types are [correlated](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) is not really easy or even possible in the general case.  The compiler will almost always think two such values are independent, unless you test them separately. Meaning: the only solutions here are going to look like: you only do enough work to convince yourself that the types are the same, and you have to tell the compiler not to worry about it via something like a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions):

```
function areas(s: Shape, ss: Shape) {
  if (s.kind !== ss.kind) return; // check if the kind of them are the same
  switch (s.kind) {
    case "square":
      return s.size * s.size + (ss as typeof s).size * (ss as typeof s).size;
    case "rectangle":
      return (
        s.height * s.width + (ss as typeof s).height * (ss as typeof s).width
      );
  }
}
```

Or, you will have to do more work than you think should be necessary so that the compiler is convinced that the only possibilities are the ones you expect.  Meaning you'll do what feels to you like redundant type guards.  I think in this case, I'd refactor your code to be like this, which only adds one more check:

```
function areas2(s: Shape, ss: Shape) {
  if (s.kind === "square" && ss.kind === "square") {
    return s.size * s.size + ss.size * ss.size;
  }
  if (s.kind === "rectangle" && ss.kind === "rectangle") {
    return (
      s.height * s.width + ss.height * ss.width
    );
  }
  return;
}
```

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoEcCucooN4BQyyA1qACYBcyARAM5Y4Q0DcRydwAXhNSJgFsARtDYBfAqEixEKAEoQEYOCADmAG3zsyIKrVxKVG5m2IB3YOTAALPoJFRTyaxGCrrYO8NEEJBMACeAA4oqNZwIcgAvGiMuMgAPsgKhmqabAQwmCBKwAD2IMhMcHQAFHTUYREQADQcFWjhIQCUyITEwDDI5QB0OuTIAIRRMXR0fRStuGCYUCAsyAD0i8gILggkyJ3INij9yHlduwJF8bsccAIQ7HQWYGvd4-2t7cSrJSj0ccyU7G-I01mhXGnB4yAAVBweqCUABqR50IqIwIhQ4cZrQ7goSHlRElHbBCBougYmFOYgID76RTKNI-P5vQFzboM-7jFxuDwQqEWKzWZDw3FIgmoroknoc9xgblC-EoolijG8mys5DNJwSPxZHJgfKFYp0ABM5UqTVq9VN1Re7G2vX2IxiX2wuBoyAAZG76hNdNERrQGM7mNb-kzgZiwZCQViBV6YdyxuGIBqbV07RRfY6DLTjK6PV77X6aFmjJoaMHGRAZszSqr2a4pfGesr+fCE5KuZHxs2Ger2BJiKHxAQgA)

Answer (score 0):

Replace your if condition as 
if (s.kind !=== ss.kind)

Hope it will work for you

Answer (score -1):

So I see a few ways to improve your code.

In my opinion, [Union Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) should only be used when the two type are disparate types.  For example, CSS allows values for some properties to either be a string or a number.  So how do you convey to the consumer of your function that you only want them to pass one of those two?  That's a good case for a Union Type:

```
var element: HtmlElement;Z
function bad(width: any) {
  element.style.width = width;
}
// no typescript error about the wrong type being passed in
bad(new Date());  

type widthType = string | number | null;
function good(width: widthType) {
  element.style.width = widthType
}
//  typescript error about the wrong type being passed in
good(new Date());
```

[Typescript Playground Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/AQ4NwQwJ2BTAbWBbWA7ALgLmACQCoCyAMgKKIoYDcAUKMAGYCuqAxugJYD2qwARhABMAFAHd2A9AAtsEVAE8AlMADetOnHJp0AOgDO6OYm1iJk4AF5gJqTToBfNSAD0T4Kk7ADAB1i6WUdi90OCgoThgIXk5GYKlYKzDUAHNPOR8+WHZk4C8IXV1YAWAsxz5BIVRYEWAAEQh0WCEFBUoQalLveOtJPDT4y30A7IAfN0YkXlgYUdRGeHhbUCZWDm5gJM5OYW7sbt6fJVV1DWQtPQMjbosrcSl92EWQBzoXEE6-AKCQsIiomM9JF1EilOhksilcvlCsVUKUNlsKlVavVGs1WsBqEA).

While many people decide to go the route of using a `kind` property, I avoid it as much as possible since it's a [Magic String](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_string).  If two types are compatible, someone must know the inter workings of your square to build there own square (yikes).  You can technically avoid that by moving to abstract classes:

```
abstract class Square {
  static kind = 'square'
}
```

But then you can just use `instanceOf`, so no real point to that.

However, in Object Oriented Programming, we need to be aware of Inheritence (is-a) and Composition (has-a).  Since both Rectangle *is-a* shape, and Square *is-a* shape, then we should be modeling our objects as such:

```
interface Shape { }
interface Rectangle : Shape { }
interface Square : Shape { }
```

Now that we have a good staring point for the models we need to take a look at the method.  What is an area?  An Area [is the quantity that expresses the extend of a two dimensional figure or **shape**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area).  So we should now modify our inheritance chain/tree/whatever to require this functionality:

```
interface Shape { 
  areas(shape: Shape): number;
}
interface Rectangle : Shape { }
interface Square : Shape { }
```

We [encapsulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) that method at the shape level, because all shapes (2D or larger assuming) have an area (0 is still a size).

It's easy to review this and thing, *why should the shapes do this calculation* and I would simply suggest many frameworks (if not most OOP frameworks) do this exact thing.  When you compare two objects in .Net via [Equals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=netframework-4.8) you should always test that the types are the same.  But notice that the method is at the root of object, not a disconnect/global method.

So this might be a good result of that improvement:

```
interface Shape { 
  // null would indicate we can't join the two
  // I prefer null to indicate a known invalid value
  // and only use undefined to indicate an unknown (always invalid) value
  areas(shape: Shape): number | null;  
}
interface Rectangle : Shape { }
interface Square : Shape { }

class MyRectangle : Rectangle  {
  width: number;
  height: number;
  area(shape: Shape){
    if (!(shape instanceOf Rectangle)) {
      return null;
    }
    return this.height * this.width + shape.height * shape.width;
  }
}

class MySquare : Square {
  size: number;
  area(shape: Shape){
    if (!(shape instanceOf Square)) {
      return null;
    }
    return this.size * this.size + shape.size * shape.size;
  }
}

// Example call:

const mySquare = new MySquare();
const mySquare2 = new MySquare();
const areas = mySquare2.area(mySquare);  // fully type checked.
```

The previous examples are good if the interfaces are a separate library then the classes, where someone might actually want to express those values differently.  If that's not the case, and there should only be 1 type of square and 1 type of rectangle, then interfaces are not the best choice, and I would suggest using classes instead.  Because implementing Circle in the previous example would be very difficult (both the interfaces and the classes need to change).  Uses classes would look like:

```
abstract class Shape {
  area(shape: Shape);
}
class Rectangle : Shape {
  width: number;
  height: number;
  area(shape: Shape){
    if (!(shape instanceOf Rectangle)) {
      return null;
    }
    return this.height * this.width + shape.height * shape.width;
  }
}
class Square: Shape {
  size: number;
  area(shape: Shape){
    if (!(shape instanceOf Square)) {
      return null;
    }
    return this.size * this.size + shape.size * shape.size;
  }
}
```

Now implementing Circle becomes trivial.

```
class Circle: Shape {
  radius: number;
  area(shape: Shape){
    if (!(shape instanceOf Circle)) {
      return null;
    }
    return this.size * this.size + shape.size * shape.size;
  }
}
```